# Mip SDK cannot decrypt office files if it is unloaded and reloaded in the same process

Tags: microsoft-information-protection, mip-sdk

In our product, we have a windows DLL which links to the MIP sdk. Our DLL can be loaded and unloaded dynamically during the lifetime of the application. Accordingly, the MIP SDK also gets loaded and unloaded. We are seeing an issue occur if the MIP SDK were unloaded and reloaded in the same process (as a result of the dependent DLL being unloaded and reloaded). After reload, when we call either mip::FileHandler::IsProtected() or FileHandler::GetFileStatus() on a protected office file (docx/xlsx/pptx), the function throws an exception "Error while creating compound file. failed creating object". This issue is seen on windows only. Also, this was not an issue in v1.8.104 of MIP SDK.

Similar to v1.8, I would expect there should be no issues even if v1.13 MIP SDK libraries are unloaded & reloaded multiple times. There should not be any difference in behavior when we call the APIs IsProtected() or GetFileStatus().